# Why adding data to datagridview with bindingsource from dataset is blank?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What i try here is, i want to Add 4 textbox to datagridview from dataset. Here is what i do,

i create a dataset and set some column with it, and then i bind the "dataset" to BindingSource which is i named them

dataset = ds1
BindingSource = bs1

then i select the datasource in datagridview with "bs1", then the column showed up, then i change the column header name. Here come my problem, i try bind 4 textbox entry to datagridview like this

```
    public void AddRow()
    {
        try
        {
            DataRow dr1 = dt1.NewRow();

            dr1["cnNo"] = dgv_details.Rows.Count + 1;
            dr1["cnProductID"] = txt_ProductID.Text;
            dr1["cnProductName"] = txt_ProductName.Text;
            dr1["cnQty"] = txt_Qty.Text;
            dr1["cnPrice"] = txt_Price.Text;

            dt1.Rows.Add();

            MessageBox.Show("Executed");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate entry");
        }
    }
```

i should work, the row is added new, but all of the row is blank, no entry is added to datagridview, what i got is new row with blank row, what i missed here?

*cnNo here mean "cn" is column name, this is how i named them in dataset column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the row:

```
dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);
```